# Excel vba to dynamically replace R(number)C(number) for pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

I'm very new to vba. As such, I've been using the "Record Macro..." functionality to get my scripts started. From that point, I hack away.

I've recorded a macro to create a pivot table that is based on data that will dynamically change as time goes on (ie. from day to day, or from month to month).

The "My_Data" table contains trouble ticket info, such as the year and month that a ticket was closed.

Here's what the recorded script looks like (though I hacked a bit by adding the simple line to create a target sheet for the pivot chart that is named "Closed"):

```
Sub CreateClosedPivot()
    Sheets("My_Data").Select
    Sheets.Add.Name = "Closed"
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "My_Data!R1C1:R210C23", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15). _
        CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Closed!R1C1", TableName:="PivotTable8" _
        , DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion15
    Sheets("Closed").Select
    Cells(1, 1).Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable8").PivotFields("Year Closed")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable8").AddDataField    ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable8").PivotFields("Month Closed"), "Count of Month Closed", xlCount
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable8").PivotFields("Month Closed")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 2
    End With
End Sub
```

As stated above, the My_Data table will change. What that means is that the static, recorded line that contains "My_Data!R1C1:R210C23" will be incorrect the next month this macro is run. Specifically, this issue is isolated to 'R210' in that line of code. The row number will change. The other numbers are static (eg C23).

I also know how to get count of the last row of My_Data:

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("My_Data")

LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

MsgBox "LastRow is " & LastRow, vbInformation
```

What would be nice would be the ability to somehow replace the static 'R210' with 'LastRow'.

If that's possible, can someone please provide the syntax to enable this substitution?

Comment: Welcome to SO Evil Patrick!  Please be sure to mark an answer as correct, this is sort of our "coin of the realm".

Answer (score 1):

`"My_Data!R1C1:R210C23"` is a string. 
You may always replace a part of a string like this:

```
"My_Data!R1C1:R" & LastRow & "C23"
```

make sure that the string includes everything needed when you replace something with a variable.